# Onsen Ui 2 not working in Chrome (with code)

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, firefox, onsen-ui2

I am using Onsen Ui but its not working right in Chrome (in firefox everything is perfect). When I open my Project in Chrome lots of faults appear:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have attributes
>
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The result must not have attributes

I just checked everything and I am very desperated. You can download my whole Code and Project, please help.

My Project: http://www.mediafire.com/file/gschd7ku2upzsk9/Schul-Voting.rar

Comment: Rather than posting a link to your complete project consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code isnt the problem its somethink else so I cant delete things from that I dont know that they play a role in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing here, I think it's related to Chrome 54.0.2840.87, no problem with older versions.
Edit : I just updated Onsen to 2.0.4 and now it's OK.